# Is it okay to re-run Install Web-Application.ps1?

Tags: dxa

I'm looking at an STRI setup that's missing the Session Preview settings in the Staging Publication Target.

The [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-E266C056-8AA6-4B7B-9700-F65F4795E002) provides an example and explains the parameters in:

```
& '.\Install Web-Application.ps1' -distDestination "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\My-site\"
-webName "My-site" -siteDomain "" -sitePort 83 -logFolder "C:\My-site\" -sitePublicationId 11 
-sessionDbServer "MySessionDBserver"
```

1. Should the script update the Publication Target's Session Preview settings (Content Delivery Endpoint URL and Website URL's)?
2. If so, is it okay to run the script with fewer parameters, just for the Session Preview setup?

I understand the alternative would be to setup up Session Preview manually, though I'd like to have the same "baseline" as other installs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web app installer will not update *anything* in the CMS, it just creates/updates the site in IIS. You need to set up Publishing (including Session Preview) yourself, manually.

There is a parameter for the installer: deployType, which if set to "Staging" ensures that additional configuration/jars are setup including the Ambient Data framework cartridge for session preview and session preview db connection (for which you need the additional parameters related to the session db)

To answer the question in your title - is it OK to re-run the installer? The answer is Yes, you can re-run it as many times as you like with tweaked configuration and it will update accordingly. I'm not sure what happens if you switch **deployType** from *Staging* to *Live* though - it may not remove unnecessary jars/config.

Comment: @AlvinReyes also take a close look at what the `$webSiteAction` parameter is set at, its default is "Preserve" so it won't update settings in ISS when you run it a second time. If you do want it to recreate your web site and application in IIS, change it to "Recreate"

Comment: I ended up doing it manually but with the example script, what would the setup have been? Two databases, a single site, and one or two websites in IIS?